# Config --no-log for an init deamon job

Tags: upstart, log, init, logging

I have a proccess configured under /etc/init and it runs by the init deamon, and want this proccess to stop sending logs to the /var/log/upstart dir.

I read this document:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/TechnicalOverviewUpstart#A--no-log

But couldnt understand the usage,
How do I set the --no-log uption for an init procces?

Thanks

Comment: Have you use that by adding them in the back of the command? For example: {command} --no-log

Comment: Where can I see the command?

Answer (score 0):

Answered when Ben posted to upstart-devel mailing list:

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/upstart-devel/2014-May/003225.html

Comment: A link by itself is not an answer. Worse, the linked-to message is misleading: it recommends running `init --no-log`, which is supposed to use `tellinit` on a running system. That does not work: `init: invalid option: --no-log`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way to do this without a reboot, but I could not find it -- invoking `/sbin/init` or `tellinit` with the `--no-log` option, as some people would recommend, simply prints out an error (at least, on Trusty):

```
# /sbin/init --no-log
init: invalid option: --no-log
Try `init --help' for more information.
```

But, if you are willing to reboot to see your changes, the open up the `/etc/default/grub` in your favorite editor, find the line setting the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` (it is usually set to empty) and add `--no-log` to it.

Then run `update-grub` and reboot.

When the machine comes back, run `lsof | grep /var/log/upstart` to see, that there are no files open in the directory. You can also check `/var/log/kern.log` to make sure, the `--no-log` is among the running kernel's arguments.